# Xamarin.Forms Launch or Wake app on bluetoothle button push

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I now have a requirement for an iOS/Android app (Xamarin.Forms) to either wake or launch when a paired BluetoothLE button is pressed.  The app may be in the background or even closed.

I have a POC app (modeled after [Acr.Ble samples](https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle/tree/master/Samples)) and I'm currently using CoreBluetooth to scan and connect to the device and get services etc...  I'm not sure what I need to do to get the app to wake or launch when the button is pressed.

I know Android and iOS may handle these things differently, so a cross-platform solution is not a requirement.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't force an app to the foreground on iOS. If you set a characteristic on your peripheral to support `notify` and then get your central app to subscribe to notification on that characteristic then your peripheral can write a value to the characteristic to trigger the notification delegate method on your app. This will give your app some background execution time to process the notification.

Comment: Thanks #Paulw11, it was the subscription to the notification characteristic piece I was missing.